# Why my webpage title shows "Apache" when webserver was changed to nginx in AWS Elastic BeanStalk

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, tomcat, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have two issues:

When I first started Elastic BeanStalk it had Apache webserver for Java8 Tomcat8 combination.

I was able to access my webapp using the link shown

a) https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmEka.png

After working on Apache, I went to configurations and changed the server to 
nginx as I would like to try nginx.

I re-deployed and restarted app server after changing my webserver to nginx in my configuration, and

- Issue 1: not able to access homepage by clicking link (as shown in a)  )
- Issue 2: The webpage title still shows as "Apache..."  Why is that?
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/l17WJ.png

But when I checked chrome console, I see nginx there.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat is an Apache Software Foundation project. Your screenshot is of an "Apache Tomcat" error page. It is not telling you that the Elastic Beanstalk reverse-proxy is Apache Web Server, it is simply telling you that the application server is Apache Tomcat.

Comment: oh ok. Got it. How about the issue 1?
When I first had Apache web server, after installation clicking the link directly takes to the home page. But the same is not happening after installing nginx. Why is that?